# Received 2 LEGO bags with no instructions

Tags: set-identification

My wife and I received 2 LEGO bags and we are trying to identify what they are so my son and I can find the manual. I’ve attached pictures, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Also this picture shows the figures included.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Both are from [Jungle Tree House (41059)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41059-1)

[image]

First polypag is identified by [Container, Barrel Half Large with Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64951) in Medium Lavender and Sand Green [Mini Doll Friends Hips and Skirt](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92252c00pb005)

Second polybag has combination of [Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6179#T=C) in Dark Pink and [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 Log](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30136) in Lavender color.

Instructions can be downloaded from [LEGO Service web page](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=41059%2520Jungle%2520Tree%2520Sanctuary%2520LEGO%2520Friends).